# How to fix error: cannot find symbol (example is active.EmailChecker(); with arrow pointing at ".")

Tags: java

So, here is my code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class EmailCheck
{

    public static boolean isValid(String email) 
    { 

        String emailRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\."+ 
                            "[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@" + 
                            "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-z" + 
                            "A-Z]{2,7}$"; 

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(emailRegex); 
        if (email == null) 
            return false; 
        return pat.matcher(email).matches(); 
    } 
}
```

then

```
public class EmailChecker extends EmailCheck
{

   public EmailChecker(String email)
   {

      if (isValid(email))
      { 
            System.out.print(email+" is an email address");
      }
      else
      {
            System.out.print(email+" is not an email address");
      }     
   }
}
```

and the main one

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EmailInput
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String email = scan.nextLine();
        EmailChecker active = new EmailChecker(email);
        active.EmailChecker();
    }   
}
```

So basically, I want to create a program that ask the user to input their email, and then the program will check whether the email is valid or not, and my lecturer also tells me that its also need to be created like that (have 1 class, then another to extend it and the main).
But it seems that if I try to compile it, it gives me error

```
C:\Java 2>javac EmailInput.java
EmailInput.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                active.EmailChecker();
                      ^
  symbol:   method EmailChecker()
  location: variable active of type EmailChecker
1 error
```

Does anybody knows how to resolve the error?

Comment: You are missing the import for EmailChecker

Comment: Umm, this code makes no sense; your logic is in the constructor of `EmailChecker` and `EmailChecker` does not define a void `EmailChecker` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change:

1.main

```
EmailChecker active = new EmailChecker();
active.checkEmailChecker(email);
```

2. EmailChecker

```
public void checkEmailChecker(String email)
```

**OR:**
1. Main only:

```
EmailChecker active = new EmailChecker(email);
```

2. EmailChecker:

```
public EmailChecker(String email)
```

Booth is working. By your solution is the problem your logic is in the constructor. So you have no  function "active.EmailChecker();"